# What exactly is the purpose of syntax objects in scheme?

Tags: scheme, eval, racket, hygiene, syntax-object

I am trying to write a small scheme-like language in python, in order to try to better understand scheme.

The problem is that I am stuck on syntax objects. I cannot implement them because I do not really understand what they are for and how they work.

To try to understand them, I played around a bit with syntax objects in DrRacket.

From what I've been able to find, evaluating `#'(+ 2 3)` is no different from evaluating `'(+ 2 3)`, except in the case that there is a lexical `+` variable shadowing the one in the top-level namespace, in which case `(eval '(+ 2 3))` still returns `5`, but `(eval #'(+ 2 3))` just throws an error.

For example:

```
(define (top-sym)
  '(+ 2 3))
(define (top-stx)
  #'(+ 2 3))
(define (shadow-sym)
  (define + *)
  '(+ 2 3))
(define (shadow-stx)
  (define + *)
  #'(+ 2 3))
```

`(eval (top-sym))`, `(eval (top-stx))`, and `(eval (shadow-sym))` all return `5`, while `(eval (shadow-stx))` throws an error. *None* of them return `6`.

If I didn't know better, I would think that the only thing that's special about syntax objects (aside from the trivial fact that they store the location of the code for better error reporting) is that they throw an error under certain circumstances where their symbol counterparts would have returned a potentially unwanted value.

If the story were that simple, there would be no real advantage to using syntax objects over regular lists and symbols.

So my question is: What am I missing about syntax objects that makes them so special?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28part._stxobj-model%29 yet?

Comment: @dyoo I have read that several times and that is what made me think I understood them, until I tried out the above tests. From that page, I would have thought that `(eval (shadow-stx))` should return `6`.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you ask about syntax objects, that's really a uniquely Racket thing: it is not a Scheme thing in general.  The syntax object is a data type that's at the heart of Racket's language infrastructure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Syntax objects are the repository for lexical context for the underlying Racket compiler.  Concretely, when we enter program like:

```
#lang racket/base
(* 3 4)
```

The compiler receives a syntax object representing the entire content of that program.  Here's an example to let us see what that syntax object looks like:

```
#lang racket/base

(define example-program 
  (open-input-string
   "
    #lang racket/base
    (* 3 4)
   "))

(read-accept-reader #t)
(define thingy (read-syntax 'the-test-program example-program))
(print thingy) (newline)
(syntax? thingy)
```

Note that the `*` in the program has a compile-time representation as a syntax object within `thingy`.  And at the moment, the `*` in `thingy` has no idea where it comes from: it has no binding information yet.  It's during the process of *expansion*, during compilation, that the compiler associates `*` as a reference to the `*` of `#lang racket/base`.

We can see this more easily if we interact with things at compile time.  (Note: I am deliberately avoiding talking about `eval` because I want to avoid mixing up discussion of what happens during compile-time vs. run-time.)

Here is an example to let us inspect more of what these syntax objects do:

```
#lang racket/base
(require (for-syntax racket/base))

;; This macro is only meant to let us see what the compiler is dealing with
;; at compile time.

(define-syntax (at-compile-time stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ expr)
     (let ()
       (define the-expr #'expr)
       (printf "I see the expression is: ~s\n" the-expr)

       ;; Ultimately, as a macro, we must return back a rewrite of
       ;; the input.  Let's just return the expr:
       the-expr)]))


(at-compile-time (* 3 4))
```

We'll use a macro here, `at-compile-time`, to let us inspect the state of things during compilation.  If you run this program in DrRacket, you will see that DrRacket first compiles the program, and then runs it.  As it compiles the program, when it sees uses of `at-compile-time`, the compiler will invoke our macro.

So at compile-time, we'll see something like:

```
I see the expression is: #<syntax:20:17 (* 3 4)>
```

Let's revise the program a little bit, and see if we can inspect the [`identifier-binding`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._identifier-binding%29%29) of identifiers:

```
#lang racket/base
(require (for-syntax racket/base))

(define-syntax (at-compile-time stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ expr)
     (let ()
       (define the-expr #'expr)
       (printf "I see the expression is: ~s\n" the-expr)
       (when (identifier? the-expr)
         (printf "The identifier binding is: ~s\n" (identifier-binding the-expr)))

       the-expr)]))


((at-compile-time *) 3 4)

(let ([* +])
  ((at-compile-time *) 3 4))
```

If we run this program in DrRacket, we'll see the following output:

```
I see the expression is: #<syntax:21:18 *>
The identifier binding is: (#<module-path-index> * #<module-path-index> * 0 0 0)
I see the expression is: #<syntax:24:20 *>
The identifier binding is: lexical
12
7
```

(By the way: why do we see the output from `at-compile-time` up front?  Because compilation is done entirely before runtime!  If we pre-compile the program and save the bytecode by using [raco make](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/make.html), we would *not* see the compiler being invoked when we run the program.)

By the time the compiler reaches the uses of `at-compile-time`, it knows to associate the appropriate lexical binding information to identifiers.  When we inspect the `identifier-binding` in the first case, the compiler knows that it's associated to a particular module (in this case, `#lang racket/base`, which is what that `module-path-index` business is about).  But in the second case, it knows that it's a *lexical* binding: the compiler already walked through the `(let ([* +]) ...)`, and so it knows that uses of `*` refer back to the binding set up by the `let`.

The Racket compiler uses syntax objects to communicate that kind of binding information to clients, such as our macros.

---

Trying to use `eval` to inspect this sort of stuff is fraught with issues: the binding information in the syntax objects might not be relevant, because by the time we evaluate the syntax objects, their bindings might refer to things that don't exist!  That's fundamentally the reason you were seeing errors in your experiments.

Still, here is one example that shows the difference between s-expressions and syntax objects:

```
#lang racket/base

(module mod1 racket/base
  (provide x)
  (define x #'(* 3 4)))

(module mod2 racket/base
  (define * +) ;; Override!
  (provide x)
  (define x  #'(* 3 4)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(require (prefix-in m1: (submod "." mod1))
         (prefix-in m2: (submod "." mod2)))

(displayln m1:x)
(displayln (syntax->datum m1:x))
(eval m1:x)

(displayln m2:x)
(displayln (syntax->datum m2:x))
(eval m2:x)
```

This example is carefully constructed so that the contents of the syntax objects refer only to module-bound things, which will exist at the time we use `eval`.  If we were to change the example slightly,

```
(module broken-mod2 racket/base
  (provide x)
  (define x  
    (let ([* +])
      #'(* 3 4))))
```

then things break horribly when we try to `eval` the `x` that comes out of `broken-mod2`, since the syntax object is referring to a lexical binding that doesn't exist by the time we `eval`.  `eval` is a difficult beast.

Comment: By the way, Matthew Flatt will be giving a talk specifically about this topic at Clojure/West 2013.  His talk http://clojurewest.org/sessions#flatt  will have a lot more examples that should help clarify.

Comment: Thanks! Will the talk be watchable online?

Comment: @Matt: I believe so, but I'm not absolutely sure.  Clojure/West 2012 does have a video archive hosted by InfoQ http://clojurewest.org/news/2012/5/11/clojurewest-video-schedule.html so I expect they will do the same for this year too.

Comment: So is there any use for syntax objects that reference lexical bindings?

Comment: Yes.  One concrete situation is in systems like Typed Racket, which to my knowledge must keep track of all bindings, both lexical and module-bound, so that it can associate types to each binding position.  Lexical references to those bindings can then be associated to their  types through comparisons like `bound-identifier=?` against the known binding positions.

Disentangle the issues you were having with syntax objects and `eval`: those issues are `eval`'s fault, not the syntax objects.  Racket programmers try to avoid `eval` unless they really know what they are doing.